# Attach EC2 in multi-region to ECS Anywhere

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a case like this:
I got 1 ECS cluster in the ap-northeast-1 region and some ec2 instances in any region the user selected. Can EC2 instances connect to the ECS cluster within the AWS network, not go through the internet?

I already tried and I can connect cross region but it required ec2 instance to obtain a public / elastic IP. Can EC2 connect to ecs only with private ip?

And how can I achieve it?
Thanks

Comment: I've never tried this, so no idea if it will work for your use case, but this looks promising https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/vpc-endpoints-cross-region-aws-services You would need to create an ECS VPC Endpoint for in each VPC the EC2 instances are in, pointing to the region your ECS cluster is in.

Comment: Your EC2 instances are in a VPC.  Your ECS cluster is in a VPC.  It seems like you need to [peer those VPCs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) with each other.  Otherwise, it isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish and there may be some missing detail in your question.